Parse string as XML and read all elements
I have a string variable that contains XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<osm attribution="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" copyright="OpenStreetMap and contributors" generator="openstreetmap-cgimap 2.0.1 (3329554 spike-07.openstreetmap.org)" license="http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/1-0/" version="0.6">
     
        <way changeset="123350178" id="26695601" timestamp="2022-07-08T08:32:16Z" uid="616103" user="Max Tenerelli" version="12" visible="true">
              
            <nd ref="289140256"/>
              
            <nd ref="292764243"/>
              
            <nd ref="291616556"/>
              
            <nd ref="292764242"/>
              
            <nd ref="291616560"/>
              
            <nd ref="291616561"/>
              
            <nd ref="291616562"/>
              
            <tag k="access" v="permissive"/>
              
            <tag k="highway" v="service"/>
              
            <tag k="maxspeed" v="30"/>
              
            <tag k="name" v="Baracconi - Jacotenente"/>
              
            <tag k="oneway" v="no"/>
              
            <tag k="surface" v="paved"/>
             
        </way>
        
    </osm>

I need to read all nd node (ref value) using Python. I built this code but it is not working:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    for eir in root.findall('nodes'):
        print(eir.text)


Your XML does not contain any nodes with tag 'nodes', so findall does not find any. Additionally, the nodes with tag 'nd' do not contain any text, just an attribute.

This xml does not contain any <nodes> elements.  Frankly I do not even understand the question.

Find all nd elements with a ref attribute and extract the attribute value: [e.get('ref') for e in root.findall('.//nd[@ref]')].


You first need to find the way element and search for nd inside
Thus don't search for nodes, but the element name: nd.
There is no .text, to get the attribute use: eir.attrib['ref']

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(input)
way = root.find('way')

for eir in way.findall('nd'):
        print(eir.attrib['ref'])

Output:
289140256
292764243
291616556
292764242
291616560
291616561
291616562


Try it online!
